# AM335x Sitara: How to change the CPU mode

Tags: embedded, arm, interrupt, bare-metal, cortex-a

I am currently starting up a bare-metal project on a TI Sitara AM 3359. In fact I use the ICE board from TI for development at this stage.

For the initialization of some of the peripherals, I need to switch to a privileged mode. System Mode would be sufficient, I suppose. Now that is where the trouble started: How do I get into System Mode?

I tried so far:

- Overwriting the instruction in the vector table:
  I store the address of my _swihandler at address 0x4030CE28.

  `ldr     r0, _swihandler
  mov     r1, #0xCE28         ; Load global vector table base address, low
  movt    r1, #0x4030         ; Load global vector table base address, high
  str     r0, [r1]`
  According to TI's documentation (spruh73h.pdf, Technical Reference Manual) this is the word which is loaded into the PC if the SWI instruction at 0x4030CE08 is executed. In the debugger I can see that the value stored is 0xE92D4001 instead of 0x4030088C where my function actually is located. Thus when SWI is executed the jump does not work. Don't know why the address is not written properly.
- Relocating the vector base address:
  I try accessing the VBAR register of CP15. Everytime I do that, I get a jump to the Undefined Exception vector address. Seems I am not allowed to do that from User Mode. I think I have some sort of a hen-and-egg problem here.
- Linking of a self-made vector table to 0x4030CE00:
  My last effort was to try and link a vector table of my own to be at the proper address and overwrite the default. Somehow I cannot find the assembler syntax for Code Composer Studio v5 to relocate my vector table. I have browsed the assembler directives listed in spnu118l.pdf (TI's Assembly Language Tools documentation), but could not find something useful. Do I have to write a scatter file or use a linker command line option?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665505/why-does-my-swi-instruction-hang-beaglebone-black-arm-cortex-a8-cpu) seems to be related to my problem.

Comment: Try `ldr r0, =_swihandler`; note the **equal** sign.  I think you are loading the first assembler instruction of `_swihandler`.  You can also use `ldr r1, =0x4030ce28`.  Google `.ltorg` and ARM literal pool.

Comment: @artlessnoise: The value of r0 is indeed the first instruction of _swihandler. I checked that. However, putting an equal-sign in front of the label does not work. It produces "Bad term in expression" and "Illegal symbol" errors.

Comment: What assembler are you using?  This is a *gnu assembler* extension.  You need the *address* placed as a data item and then loaded.  You can also try `adrl r0,_swihandler`.  See: [GAS ARM pseudo-ops](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html)

Comment: @artlessnoise: The assembler is the one that comes with Code Composer Studio. It should be some sort of gcc derivative. `adrl` works, but yields a warning "Invalid instruction modifier(s) ignored". Using just `adr` does also work, but without the warning.

Comment: So `adr r0, _swihandler` assembles or it completely fixes the issue?  Often which pseudo-operation to use depends on the location of the `_swihandler` versus the code.  If the `_swihandler` is external, you need a [`.globl`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Global.html) where it is defined.

Comment: @artlessnoise: `adr r0, _swihandler` fixes the issue. `_swihandler` is also assembly code standing right next to the code in question. I ran into some other peculiarities with the CCSv5 assembler in the last days. I finally found [this guide to port assembly from KEIL to CCS](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/arm/ConvertKeilCCS.pdf) which was lots of help to me...